# Combining Code and UI - Example: DartsScoringApplication

Tags: java, user-interface, module, structure

I'm a student in third semester and to get more into programming Java I started a project. I want to program a DartScoringApplication. The functional code itself is not the biggest challenge, but the organization. I want to reuse the code later to create an App in Android Studio.

I'm not sure how to structure code and UI though. When the program starts it loads existing players in MenuTest from txt-file into an Array-Object player. I could hand over the Player-Object to dozens of functions now, but then I'm not able to reuse it easily. And I've learned at least in theory that learning a good code structure is most important. Do you have any tips? Thanks:)

````
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MenuTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  
    private JMenuItem doSomething = null;
    private JMenuItem exit = null;
    private JMenuItem help = null;
    private JMenuItem about = null;

    private JLabel text = null;


    public MenuTest() throws FileNotFoundException{

        setTitle("Menu-Test");

        int spieleranzahl;
        Spielermanagement sm = new Spielermanagement();
        spieleranzahl = sm.lade_SpielerAnzahl("src/spieler/Spieler.txt");
        Spieler[] spieler = new Spieler[spieleranzahl];
        spieler = sm.lade_Spieler("src/spieler/Spieler.txt");





        text = new JLabel("Diese Anwendung demonstriert die Verwendung von Menüs");






        getContentPane().add(text);




        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if (evt.getSource() == doSomething) {
            System.out.println("Mach Was");
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == about) {
            System.out.println("Programm erstellt von mir");
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == help) {
            System.out.println("Das Programm ist hilflos");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        MenuTest test = new MenuTest();
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Take a look at Model-View-Controller Pattern (MVC). A pattern used to separate application's concerns. To get started you might want to look [here](https://javabeginners.de/Design_Patterns/Model-View-Controller.php) or [here](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_19_016.htm) first.

Comment: thanks! I will look into that!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to
improve code formatting.
See [ask]